# Array program only outputs "int 32"

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2017

Need a program that can make an array with values 0-50 and then output them in a list. It seems to just output 'int 32'. Any ideas of what is wrong?

```
    Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim Numbers(50) As Integer
        Dim Index As Integer
        Do Until Numbers(Index) <= 50
            Index = Index + 1
            Numbers(Index) = Index
        Loop
        lstnumbers.Items.Add(Numbers)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Please use 4 space indentation (Ctrl+K) to format your code..

Comment: @user202729 okay done that

Comment: What is this? VisualBasic? VB.net? Please tag accordingly. (Doesn't seem specific to Studio 2017.)

Comment: there was a vb.net tag but its not showing

Comment: The `Items.Add()` method takes only one item at a time. You've either got to add the each number one-by-one in a loop, or use the `Items.AddRange()` method instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few little changes...Do Until < will give a bunch of zeros
Also moved a few things around to avoid Index out of range and to get zero in there.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim Numbers(50) As Integer
        Dim Index As Integer
        Do Until Index >= 51
            Numbers(Index) = Index
            lstNumbers.Items.Add(Numbers(Index))
            Index = Index + 1
        Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Two options here:

**One:**

```
   Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim lstnumbers As New ArrayList()
        Dim Numbers(50) As Integer
        Dim Index As Integer
        Do Until Numbers(Index) <= 50
            Index = Index + 1
            Numbers(Index) = Index
        Loop
        lstnumbers.AddRange(Numbers)
    End Sub
End Class
```

**Two:**

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim Numbers(50) As Integer
        Dim Index As Integer
        Do Until Numbers(Index) <= 50
            Index = Index + 1
            Numbers(Index) = Index
            lstnumbers.Items.Add(Index)
        Loop
    End Sub
End Class
```

This is because `Items.Add` **take only one item every time**, meaning that `Items.Add(Numbers)` will add only `int 32`.

ArrayList `AddRange` takes a queue and adds it's range, however if you know how many elements exactly your `ArrayList` will contain it is not recommended to use it, as it's size is dynamically changing.

In this example it makes no difference, as you already use a list.